# devexpress display tagbox data in datagrid cell

Tags: datagrid, devextreme

I'm working on a data grid and I ran into an issue.
I have a form that includes a tag box to let the user select multiple items.
Now, I'm creating a data grid to display this information in it.

I have managed to add the dropdown for the column filter to display the data but unfortunately, I'm not able to display the tag box info in the row. I did the exact same thing for normal dropdown (country, province).

Is there a way to display the tag box info on the data grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **customizeText** and join the array

```
<Column 
   dataField='availablecurrencies' 
   caption="Available Currencies"
   dataType='string'
   customizeText={(cellInfo) => cellInfo.value.join(',')}
/>
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all. I managed to display the text but the problem now is with the filter.